# Why do defining type name is optional in an if statement?

Tags: c++, c++17

Saw several examples that doesn't define type name for Y side and I used to to think C++ is type-strict. Is it safe to use a code snippet like below one in production?

I also curious to hear why it works..

```html
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string X = "car";

    if (X == "nothing") {
        return 1
    }
    else if (X == "car") {
        return 0 
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion and in this case a conversion isn't even necessary https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

Comment: `X`is of type string and the right side is a string literal. I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to operator== overload, std::string can compare to char* as well as to other std::string.
This is perfectly OK.